# Is there a way to show a div inside a div that has a false v-if statement

Tags: javascript, css, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, vue.js

I am using Laravel 6 and Vue.js 2.

I am using a for loop to loop through users and display their info in div's as seen below.

I have the Category names stored in user.pivot.demo2. The users are arranged by category via lodash

```
_.orderBy(this.category.users, ['pivot.demo2', 'pivot.demo3'])
```

I need the div with the class of row to only display once for each category. I have the category name set to only display if the category name is the first in the list or does not match the previous name. This separates all the users by category when displaying and puts a the category caption on top of their prospective divs and works just fine. But I need the outer div with a class of row to only be made once per category then filled with the users div that has a class of col-lg-4.

In Laravel's Blade I would just use something like

```
@if(category != the-same-category)
<div class="row">
@endif
if (category == the-same-category)
<div class="col-lg-4">{{ User.name }} </div>
@endif

@if(category != the-same-category)
</div>
@endif
```

That would allow for the div with a class of row to only show once per category but the inner divs with the class of col-lg-4 to repeat on every loop. It would also close the div at the end of the condition and each category would have their own divs with the user inside of a single row div. I don't seem to be able to find a Vue.js option that will allow this type of behavior. Can anyone suggest a JavaScript or Vue.js solution?

What I have so far is the code below

```
   <div class="outer-div text-center" v-for="(user, index) in the_category.users" :key="user.id">
  <div v-if="index === 0 || user.pivot.demo2 != the_category.users[index -1].pivot.demo2">
    <div class="text-center header-one">
      <h2>{{ user.pivot.demo2 }}</h2>
    </div>
    <hr />
    </div>

<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center"> // display once per category
  <div class="outer-profile-div col-md-4"> // display every loop
    <div class="user-name text-center">{{ user.name }}</div>
    <div class="user-title text-center">{{ user.title }}</div>     
  </div>
</div>
```

My overall goal is to display the (.outer-profile-div)'s next o each other and wrap like typical bootstrap divs inside a .row while maintaining the responsive nature of bootstrap. I don't mind using CSS, JavaScript, Vue.js or whatever will deliver the desired results.

Comment: Would restructuring the data using a computed property be an acceptable solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are probably looking for something like this. With this code you can keep a parent element while looping only the childs. It gives you the possibilty to use the conditional directives on the childs due to the template tag had became the parent.

-Example from vue-js docs- 
Try it to your problem and tell me if it solves it

```
<ul>
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <li>{{ item.msg }}</li>
    <li class="divider" role="presentation"></li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for trying to help Arthurin. However, I don't think you understood the question and so the code you provided does not work for me.

Comment: Sorry, I think now I understand your question... I think you need to rearrange your array. To achieve that using loops you will probably need an array of categories with and array of users inside, so you just loop through categories in your row and in your cols you loop through the users array (that is inside categories array)